# Loop through playlist - jquery - videojs

Tags: jquery, html5-video, video.js, playlist

I'm trying to build a simple playlist (using VideoJS and it's Dailymotion plugin) by combining some code snippets. I've managed to get some basic functionality and I'm getting close to what I want. Now I would like to update it to auto move to the next item in the playlist and to move to the first item again if there's no next item in the list. I thought I could use the callback when a vid ended, but this doesn't seem to work. The next item seems to be random.

```
    // Video ended find next
      $("#myPlayer").on("ended", function(){ 

        if ($("#list li.selected").next("li").length > 0) {
        // There are items left to play, find next li
        $("#list").find("li.selected").next('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');        
            } else {
              // No more items left to play, start again with first li
            $("#list").find("li:first").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            }

            playerload();
  });
```

sample html

```
  <div>Playlist - Coming up: <span id="current-tag"></span>
     </div>

    <ul id="list" class="list">
    <li class="playlist-item selected first" data-id="x15xo13" class="selected"><a href="#" >Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="playlist-item" data-id="x1b6fu"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="playlist-item" data-id="x21uwpw"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="playlist-item" data-id="x1ux5t"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Whole code so far

```
<script>
(function( $ ){

var player = videojs("myPlayer");

$( "#prev, #next" ).on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
 // Find the right item to load
prevnext(); 
// Load player   
playerload();  

});


$( "#list" ).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
 // Find the right item to load
 $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
// Load player
 playerload(); 

});

function initplayer() {
("myPlayer", {"techOrder": ["dailymotion"]}, function(){
// Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
}

function prevnext() {
// Browse through itemlist and highligh the selected item
var list = $('#list').find('>li');
var $new, $selected = $(".selected");
$new = (event.target.id == "prev") ? ($selected.index() == 0 ? list.last() :       $selected.prev()) : ($selected.index() == list.last().index() ? list.first() :     $selected.next());
$selected.removeClass("selected");
$new.addClass("selected");
$("#current-tag").text($new.attr('class') + $new.index());
 }

function playerload() {
// load player
initplayer();


// the list should be updated and ready with either the click or the previous/next selected value or after the ended callback
var itemUrl = $("#list").find("li.selected").data('id');
var baselink = "http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/" + itemUrl + "?api=postMessage&autoplay=1&related=0&chromeless=1&controls=html&format=json&html=1&id=myPlayer_dailymotion_api&info=1&logo=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymotion.com%2Fvideo%2F" + itemUrl + "&wmode=opaque";

   player.ready(function() {
  $("#myPLayer").removeClass("vjs-playing").addClass("vjs-paused");
  $("#myPlayer_dailymotion_api").hide();
  $("#myPlayer iframe").removeAttr("src");
  $("#myPlayer iframe").attr("src", baselink);
  $(".vjs-big-play-button").css("display","none!important"); 
  player.play();
  $("#myPlayer_dailymotion_api").show();


 // Video ended find next
  $("#myPlayer").on("ended", function(){ 

        if ($("#list li.selected").next("li").length > 0) {
        // There are items left to play, find next li
            $("#list").find("li.selected").next('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');        
            } else {
              // No more items left to play, start again with first li
            $("#list").find("li:first").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            }

            playerload();
  }); 



});
 }


})( jQuery );
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a precise answer (would have left as a comment but don't have enough rep to do so) — but when the video end event occurs how about trying to locate the currently selected item, traversing to its next sibling and triggering the click event? Something like this:

```
player.on( 'ended', function() {
    $('.selected').next('li').trigger('click');
});
```

As far as looping when you reach the last list-item in your `$#list` element why not use jQuery's `:last` selector (http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and then `.trigger` the click event on the first item by using the `:first` selector (http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)?

Pretty sure these would get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to loop through your videos:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Here I am caching the video element in a variable
        var $video = $('#backgroundVideo_video');

        $video.on('ended', function () {
            var video  = $(this).get(0);
            var player = video.player;

            player.loop(true);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```